# How to create image with unknown width and height ?

Tags: php, php-gd

I want to create an image from a string and be abble to use this image as a background for a pdf that I'm generating.

This is almost not an issue. I want the image generated to be a full size image and I know have two choices :

First : Say that the image has a fixed size and find a way to say that the name has to be full size (The image created is the text with a 45° rotation beginning at the end bottom left of the image).

Second : Say that the image has a various size depending on the size used by the name.

I don't know if I made myself clear, but if anyone has any idea, please let me know !

PS : this is my code for the moment :

```
    // Création de l'image
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor();

    // Création de quelques couleurs
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 240, 240, 240);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 400, 500, $white);

    // Le texte à dessiner
    $text = $this->user->data->display_name;

    // Définition de la variable d'environnement pour GD
    putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
    // Remplacez le chemin par votre propre chemin de police
    $font = 'arial.ttf';


    // Ajout du texte
    imagettftext($im, 100, 45, 100, 500, $grey, $font, $text);

    // Utiliser imagepng() donnera un texte plus claire,
    // comparé à l'utilisation de la fonction imagejpeg()
    $this->watermark = 'watermark/'.date('Y-m-d-H-i-s').'.png';
    imagepng($im, $this->watermark);
    imagedestroy($im);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the font you are going to use to create the image from the text, you can use `imagettfbbox()` to determine the watermark size and then use `imagecreatetruecolor()` to generate the image.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php